# How can I include the SVGKit into my Rubymotion project?

Tags: ios, xcode, rubymotion

I'm trying to use [SVGKit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit) in my Rubymotion project but can't seem to get it to build.

So far I've moved the SVGKit code into vendor/SVGKit and added the following to my Rakefile (it's an otherwise blank project)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
$:.unshift("/Library/RubyMotion/lib")
require 'motion/project/template/ios'

begin
  require 'bundler'
  Bundler.require
rescue LoadError
end

Motion::Project::App.setup do |app|
  app.name = 'SVGKitMotion'
  app.frameworks += %w[ CoreText CoreImage libxml2.dylib QuartzCore CoreGraphics UIKit ]

  app.vendor_project('vendor/SVGKit', :static,
      :products => ["libSVGKit-iOS.1.2.0pre.a"])

end
```

when I try to build it - I get the following:

```
     Build ./build/iPhoneSimulator-7.0-Development
     Build vendor/SVGKit
   Compile vendor/SVGKit/Source/DOM classes/Core DOM/AppleSucksDOMImplementation.m
   Compile vendor/SVGKit/Source/DOM classes/Core DOM/Attr.m
   Compile vendor/SVGKit/Source/DOM classes/Core DOM/CDATASection.m
   Compile vendor/SVGKit/Source/DOM classes/Core DOM/CharacterData.m
   Compile vendor/SVGKit/Source/DOM classes/Core DOM/Comment.m
   Compile vendor/SVGKit/Source/DOM classes/Core DOM/CSSPrimitiveValue.m
   Compile vendor/SVGKit/Source/DOM classes/Core DOM/CSSRule.m
   Compile vendor/SVGKit/Source/DOM classes/Core DOM/CSSRuleList.m
   Compile vendor/SVGKit/Source/DOM classes/Core DOM/CSSStyleDeclaration.m
   Compile vendor/SVGKit/Source/DOM classes/Core DOM/CSSStyleRule.m
   Compile vendor/SVGKit/Source/DOM classes/Core DOM/CSSStyleSheet.m
   Compile vendor/SVGKit/Source/DOM classes/Core DOM/CSSValue.m
   Compile vendor/SVGKit/Source/DOM classes/Core DOM/CSSValueList.m
Source/DOM classes/Core DOM/CSSValueList.m:47:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'DDLogVerbose' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        DDLogVerbose(@"[%@] received new CSS Text, need to split this and save as CSSValue instances: %@", [self class], _cssText);
        ^
1 warning generated.
   Compile vendor/SVGKit/Source/DOM classes/Core DOM/Document.m
Source/DOM classes/Core DOM/Document.m:26:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'DDLogVerbose' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        DDLogVerbose( @"[%@] WARNING: SVG Spec, missing feature: if there are known attributes with default values, Attr nodes representing them SHOUL...
        ^
1 warning generated.
   Compile vendor/SVGKit/Source/DOM classes/Core DOM/DocumentFragment.m
   Compile vendor/SVGKit/Source/DOM classes/Core DOM/DocumentType.m
   Compile vendor/SVGKit/Source/DOM classes/Core DOM/DOMHelperUtilities.m
   Compile vendor/SVGKit/Source/DOM classes/Core DOM/Element.m
   Compile vendor/SVGKit/Source/DOM classes/Core DOM/EntityReference.m
   Compile vendor/SVGKit/Source/DOM classes/Core DOM/MediaList.m
   Compile vendor/SVGKit/Source/DOM classes/Core DOM/NamedNodeMap.m
   Compile vendor/SVGKit/Source/DOM classes/Core DOM/Node.m
   Compile vendor/SVGKit/Source/DOM classes/Core DOM/NodeList.m
   Compile vendor/SVGKit/Source/DOM classes/Core DOM/ProcessingInstruction.m
   Compile vendor/SVGKit/Source/DOM classes/Core DOM/StyleSheet.m
   Compile vendor/SVGKit/Source/DOM classes/Core DOM/StyleSheetList.m
   Compile vendor/SVGKit/Source/DOM classes/Core DOM/Text.m
   Compile vendor/SVGKit/Source/DOM classes/SVG-DOM/SVGAngle.m
   Compile vendor/SVGKit/Source/DOM classes/SVG-DOM/SVGAnimatedPreserveAspectRatio.m
   Compile vendor/SVGKit/Source/DOM classes/SVG-DOM/SVGDefsElement.m
In file included from Source/DOM classes/SVG-DOM/SVGDefsElement.m:1:
Source/DOM classes/SVG-DOM/SVGDefsElement.h:5:9: fatal error: 'SVGElement.h' file not found
#import "SVGElement.h"
        ^
1 error generated.
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer...]
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/vendor.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in build_static'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/vendor.rb:72:in `each'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/vendor.rb:72:in `block in build_static'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/vendor.rb:65:in `chdir'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/vendor.rb:65:in `build_static'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/vendor.rb:42:in `build'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/builder.rb:65:in `block in build'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/builder.rb:64:in `each'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/builder.rb:64:in `build'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/app.rb:76:in `build'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/template/ios.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/template/ios.rb:63:in `block in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => build:simulator
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Can anybody offer suggestions on where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DDLogVerbose is a function from [CocoaLumberjack](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack). Your best bet to make this easy would be to install SVGKit via CocoaPods. To do so, first install motion-cocoapods

```
sudo gem install motion-cocoapods
```

This should install cocoapods and motion-cocoapods. You need to setup cocoapods so run

```
pod setup
```

Now you can add motion-cocoapods to your Gemfile

```
gem 'motion-cocoapods'
```

Next add the pod to your rake file

```
app.pods do
  pod 'SVGKit'
end
```

Finally run the following rake command to download SVGKit

```
rake pod:install
```

Next time you rake, everything should theoretically just compile and work! Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks @DiGiTaLFX - I actually tried cocoa pods initially but couldn't get it to work. Does this code work for you? https://github.com/Bodacious/SVGKitMotion

Comment: Ah, ok it looks like whilst this issue was fixed in SVGKit 6 months ago, they haven't submitted an updated podspec to CocoaPods for 11 months. If you run `rake pod:install` and then replace the offending SVGRectElement.m file with the following version from github, it compiles and the app runs happily.

https://raw.github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit/1.x/Source/DOM%20classes/Unported%20or%20Partial%20DOM/SVGRectElement.m

Comment: I had to use `pod 'SVGKit', git: 'https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit.git'` to get a version that would compile for me.